# Equivalent of (a+b) / (c+d) =?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've an equation (a+b) / (c+d)

I'm wanting to bring out a/c and b/d, but I realize that (a+b) / (c+d) is not equal to (a/c) + (b/d). Yet I'm wanting something like that. So that I can multiply (a/c) by an X and (b/d) by a Y for ...

To help understand what I'm doing. Here's the computer code. I'm taking

```
lightHistory[currentHistoryIndex] = (topTotal + bottomTotal) / (pixelStorageTop.Num() + pixelStorageBottom.Num())
```

And turning it into

```
top = topTotal / pixelStorageTop.Num() * TopDetectorConsiderationPercentage;
bottom = bottomTotal / pixelStorageBottom.Num() * BottomDetectorConsiderationPercentage;
lightHistory[currentHistoryIndex] = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{a+b}{c+d} = \frac{a}{c+d} + \frac{b}{c+d} = \frac{a}{c}\cdot\frac{c}{c+d} + \frac{b}{d}\cdot\frac{d}{c+d}$$

So you can take $X=\frac{c}{c+d}$ and $Y=\frac{d}{c+d}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful

Answer (score 1):

What can be said : if it happens for example that

$$\frac{a}{c} \le \frac{b}{d}$$

it is easy to prove that

$$\frac{a}{c} \le \frac{a+b}{c+d} \le \frac{b}{d}.$$

Moreover, there exists $k=\frac{c}{c+d}$ such that

$$\frac{a+b}{c+d} =k \frac{a}{c} + (1-k) \frac{b}{d}$$

($k=\frac{c}{c+d}$ and $1-k=\frac{c}{c+d}$ are called barycentric "weights" given to the extreme fractions to get the intermediate fraction)